# check if BalloonTooltip was closed by user

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, tooltip

how can I check if BalloonTip attached to NotifyIcon was closed by user clicking "Close" icon or had dissapeared after give timeout? It seems that BalloonTipClosed is fired in both cases, and BaloonTipClicked is fired when user clicks anywhere on appearing tooltip...

Comment: Why do you want to know this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: To know if tooltip was perceived by user or not.

Comment: It's not particularly relevant if they've seen the tooltip or not. The whole point of a tooltip is that there's no required action. If you absolutely need to ensure that they've seen it, use a message box instead. You don't want to pester them by showing the tooltip over and over unless they manually dismiss it. This is bad UI design.

Comment: Well, a little background: it's a tooltip showing how many "messages" user has since given time. If he closes manually tooltip, I assume that he's ok with this and I can set since = now.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to wait until he or she has *read* those messages? And by that I probably mean "opened" them. The same as e-mail and chat programs do when they display such types of notifications?

Comment: "messages" are in completely different system, and here I am making just desktop notification with a counter. I can't determine wheter "message" is "read" or not

Comment: Maybe you should display message count on notifiyIcon (e.g Skype) and if user click on notify icon you can assume that he saw it

Comment: @Stecya It will be a little bit counter-intuitive - normal user will just close box, and I don't want force him to do anything "unusual"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to determine the close button being clicked over the balloon being clicked.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)! lists the messages sent by the Notify Icon.  It would appear from that list that there is no distinction between a user clicking the balloon and the user clicking the close button.

As commented below [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/10/14/55287.aspx) explains why the clicking of the close button does not raise a separate event.

However, this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/05/04/9585032.aspx) has a comment suggesting that, on Windows XP, NIN_BALLOONTIMEOUT is sent when the user clicks the close button. It would be against best practice to rely on quirks like this to make your program run.

Could you implement your own timer that will close the baloon tip upon completion?
Make sure you set the balloon tip to display for longer than the timer.
Then you can detect whether the timer is still running when the balloon is closed, if not then the timeout closed the balloon, otherwise the user did.

Comment: Right, it's impossible. I'm not sure why you're focusing on a comment to that blog rather than the entry itself. There's a link that explicitly says this isn't possible. [Why don't notification icons get a message when the user clicks the "X" button?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/10/14/55287.aspx): **"If such a notification were generated, ill-behaved programs would just react to a click on the balloon's "X" button with an annoying follow-up dialog like, 'Are you sure you want to ignore my wonderful message?' So there was a conscious decision not to give them the chance."**

Comment: a little bit exaggerated IMHO

Comment: @ts: Not at all. I've literally *seen* that happen. Raymond Chen's blog is a really mandatory reading for all Windows developers. You'll develop a real appreciation for why you shouldn't break all the rules. It annoys the hell out of your users, even if you think it seems like a good idea at the time. It also gives you and the Windows team hell when it comes to releasing a new version of Windows. Your app doesn't work, and you blame them for "breaking" it. Your customers, of course, couldn't care less who is to blame, they're just unhappy with both of you.

Comment: So even if (as the comments suggest) this might work on Windows XP, it isn't likely to work on future versions, and relying on undocumented behavior is a *very* bad practice to get into. Since the documentation doesn't say that you can rely on this message getting sent in this circumstance, there's no guarantee that the Windows team will ensure that it always will with future versions.

Comment: I am targeting Windows 7 only, so NIN_BALLOONTIMEOUT is not an option